# trying to get a canvas into a bitmap in c# wpf for displaying on spi display for raspi 2

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to convert a canvas object into a bitmap or an image in c#. The problem I have is, that many tutorials with "RenderTargetBitmap" won't work for me because the object methods are not awaylible for me in a windows universal app.

the later processing of the bitmap for spi output is not that problem.

alternatively I am looking for an other possibility to create an empty image an manipulate this like

Image i = new Image(width, height)
i.setText(left, top, text)

Comment: See the online documentation for [RenderTargetBitmap for UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx). UWP is not WPF. It is a different framework.

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped me :)